# Windows Server 2012 and Google Drive for Desktop

Tags: google-drive-for-desktop

I have a Windows Server 2012 with about 100 users who do not have access to each others' accounts and whose accounts are restricted to only allow access to certain applications.

Each user also has their own Google account. I want to install Google Drive for Desktop for each user.

Is it possible to have all these accounts running Google Drive for Desktop at the same time?

Comment: Welcome to [su]. Checkout [Set up Drive for desktop for your organization](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7491144?hl=en) and [Advanced Drive for desktop configuration](https://support.google.com/a/answer/7644837). If you need further help, please show what you have tried